# Exit prompt is not working when use Navigation.PushAsync for loading a new page

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am showing a prompt for the exit when a user taps the device back button on the home page.

My code:

```
private bool AcceptBack;
public static Action EmulateBackPressed;

protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    bool value = true;
    var i = this.Children.IndexOf(this.CurrentPage);
    if (i == 0)
    {
        if (AcceptBack)
            return false;
        PromptForExit();
        value = true;
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentPage = Children[0];
        value = true;
    }
    return value;
}

private async void PromptForExit()
{
    if (await DisplayAlert("Confirm to Quit?", "Are you sure you want to quit?", "Yes", "No"))
    {
        AcceptBack = true;
        EmulateBackPressed();
    }
}
```

On MainActivity:

```
Pages.CarouselHomePage.EmulateBackPressed = OnBackPressed;
```

It was working fine when I use the `Navigation.PushModalAsync` to load new pages. Currently, I am using `Navigation.PushAsync` for loading new pages; after that, the exit prompt is not showing. When I tap the backbutton it showing the previous page. In my case the homepage is a CarouselPage having 3 children.

Comment: Did you want to exit the app directly instead of return to the preview page ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I have created a sample, can you have a look? https://drive.google.com/file/d/18ReKpqokI9qsl89Ja97fmIydSFgifKTD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Sample flow: App.xaml -> Login -> CarouselHomePage
When clicking the label on the login, I will redirect to CarouselHomePage. At that time, the exit prompt is showing. But when we open the app next time I redirected the user to CarouselHomePage without showing the login(auto login). At this time, the exit prompt is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the logic of handling navigation to the method **OnAppearing** .As in the
constructor the page has not finished loading yet .

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    try
    {
        string login = Application.Current.Properties["islogin"].ToString();

        if (login == "true"&&isFirstLoad)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new CarouselHomePage(), true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("IsLogin::" + e);
    }
    isFirstLoad = false;
}

public async void LoadMainPage(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Properties["islogin"] = "true";
    await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();

    App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new CarouselHomePage());
}
```

#### in CarouselHomePage

```
private async void PromptForExit()
{
   
    if (await DisplayAlert("Confirm to Quit?", "Are you sure you want to quit?", "Yes", "No"))
    {
        Application.Current.Properties["islogin"] = "false";
        await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();

        AcceptBack = true;
        App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
    }
}
```

Comment: The exit alert is working now, but if I click the yes option from the alert app is not exiting. Also, the back button is not triggering after clicking the yes option.

Comment: You need to set the value as false `Application.Current.Properties["islogin"] = "false";
Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();`

Comment: I need to exit the app when click yes, no need to set the islogin value to false and show the login page to the user.

Comment: Sorry, It is not working. App is not exit when click yes

Comment: This is fine. Actually, I just want to close the app if I press the yes option. No need to show the login page to the user. Can you suggest a way to close the app when click yes option?